# Keep track of velocity

Tags: java, libgdx

My current motion is calculated.

```
        //moveX and Y are normalized
        moveX = moveX * time * speed;
        moveY = moveY * time * speed;
```

Of course this results in a very rigid motion that simply stops and goes.

What is an effective way to keep track of accelaration to create a speed up / slow down effect? My game has no gravity as it is top down.

Comment: you are most likely looking for an `easing function`, something akin to https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Universal-Tween-Engine

Answer (score 0):

Have separate current speed and target speed variables.

Use a constant acceleration to converge the current speed towards the target speed (for example, in each `paint(Graphics)` call).

And updating position should be something like `posX += current_speedX`; don't integrate at each call by multiplying time and speed (since that won't scale to non-linear motion).

Answer (score 0):

You need to limit the time to a short value and change speed with a constant acceleration acceleration function. So you can simulate gravity or other acceleration functions.

As an example for gravity where g is the gravity acceleration only for y axis. SpeedX is constant. The interval is 100 ms (equivalent to 0.1 seconds). SpeedY changes on the effect of g acceleration.

```
while (true) {
    moveX = moveX * 100 * speedX;
    moveY = moveY * 100 * speedY;
    speedY = speedY + g * 0.1;
    Thread.sleep(100);
}
```

Comment: How about a top down game with no gravity. How would I make an object speed up and slow down slowly instead of all at once.